# How to place scrollable ads in my flutter app with admob?

Tags: android, flutter, admob, ads, mobile-application

I'm developing a social media app using flutter. I know almost nothing about Admob and placing ads on an app.

In my app there is a feed where users scroll and see content. I want to place ads in this scroll view, randomly in between the posts. Is it possible? I mean, user will scroll thorough the feed and will randomly see ads and will scroll pass it. How can I do it?

Comment: I recommend watching this tutorial from the Flutter team https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m0d_pbgeeG8 They included how to do that in their videos.